# Multiple results output files with Jasmine Reporters

Tags: output, jasmine, protractor

I've got jasmine reporters set up and working great with my tests, writing output properly to the path I declare in each of my Conf.js files that I have associated with each Spec file.  Now, I'd like to know if I can have it write an output file for each individual spec that is run as part of a suite. (I'm not using the 'Suites' option.)  So, my conf.js file looks like this:

```
//Specs to use (All in folder)
specs: [
'.../**/*Spec.js'
],

onPrepare: function() {
//Setup Jasmine Reporters and output directory
require('<jasmine reporters path>')
var outputPath = "<my path>"
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(outputPath, true, true));
},
```

This will run all the *Spec.js files in the folder I've identified, but of course will overwrite the output after each Spec is run.  What I'd like for it to do is write a unique xml file for each Spec file that is run, so I can see the results from each individual Spec.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Following link has the parameters mentioned for the JUnitXMLReporter . By working with the parameters for the class, i guess we can acheive suite specifi files. Does this solve? [[https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/src/junit_reporter.js]]

Answer (score 2):

The closest `jasmine-reporters` offers to what you are asking for is the `consolidate` option. If set to `false`, a specific XML file will be created for each `describe` block, but there is no option to create an XML file for each `it` in your test suite.

Creating an individual file for each spec could get tricky in cases where there are tests that are skipped / disabled, but if you think this is an important feature then consider creating a pull request with what you are looking for.